# Python random, классы

Tags: python, классы, циклы, случайные-числа

У меня есть задание, которое я не могу выполнить помогите пожалуйста:
создайте класс `Die` с одним атрибутом `sides`, который имеет значение по умолчанию **`6`**.
Напишите метод `roll_over()` для вывода случайного числа от **`1`** до количества граней на кубике.

Создайте экземпляр,представляющий **`6`**-гранный кубик, и смоделируйте **`10`** бросков.

Создайте экземпляры, представляющие **`10`** и **`20`** гранный кубик.

Смоделируйте **`10`** бросков каждого кубика.

Помогите сделать это задание.

Я написал программу:

```
from random import randint 


class Die(): 
    def __init__(self, sides): 
        self.sides = sides 
        
    def roll_die(self): 
        x = randint(1, self.sides) 
        print(f'x = {x}') 
        a = 1 
        while a <= self.sides: 
            print(f'a = {a}') 
            a += 1 
            
кубик_6_граней = Die(6) 
кубик_6_граней.roll_die() 

кубик_10_граней = Die(10) 
кубик_10_граней.roll_die() 

кубик_20_граней = Die(20) 
кубик_20_граней.roll_die()
```

только я не знаю как разделить числа, то-есть как вписать сюда `\n`

Comment: а где ваши попытки...

Comment: Я написал программу:

Comment: class Die():
    def __init__(self, sides):
        self.sides = sides


    def roll_die(self):
        from random import randint
        x = randint(1, self.sides)
        print(x)
        a = 1
        while a <= self.sides:
            print(a)
            a += 1

 

кубик_6_граней = Die(6)
кубик_6_граней.roll_die()

кубик_10_граней = Die(10)
кубик_10_граней.roll_die()

кубик_20_граней = Die(20)
кубик_20_граней.roll_die()

Comment: только я не знаю как разделить числа, то-есть как вписать сюда \n

Comment: что-то не совсем понимаю какие числа вы хотите делить и зачем

Comment: По умолчанию `print` и так каждый раз на новой строке печатает, так что непонятно, что вы хотите

Comment: Только вот `roll_die` должна одно число выдавать и эту функцию надо в цикле вызывать, а вы что-то непонятное делаете, цикл внутри функции не нужен.

Comment: и смысл от этого кода `a = 1 
        while a <= self.sides: 
            print(f'a = {a}') 
            a += 1` если вам всегда надо 10 бросков моделировать

Comment: напишите, программу так, как вы считаете нужным

Comment: Vadim.Sharoikin как лучше сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум надо добавить атрибуту значение по умолчанию. Плюс моделировать броски лучше в отдельной функции.

```
from random import randint 


class Die(): 
    def __init__(self, sides=6): 
        self.sides = sides 
        
    def roll_die(self): 
        return randint(1, self.sides) 


def model_roll(die,n=10):
    print(f'Кубик {die.sides} граней')
    for i in range(n):
        print(die.roll_die())

model_roll(Die())
model_roll(Die(10))
model_roll(Die(20))
```

P.S. функция `model_rollа` принимает 2 параметра, 1 это экземпляр класса , второй, не обязательный, количество бросков по умолчанию их 10.

Answer (score 0):

может от вас вот этого хотят?:

```
from random import randint 

class Die(): 
    def __init__(self, sides): 
        self.sides = sides 
        
    def roll_die(self): 
        for i in range(10):
            print(f'{i+1} - {randint(1, self.sides)}')

            
кубик_20_граней = Die(20) 
кубик_20_граней.roll_die() 
'''
1 - 10
2 - 6
3 - 13
4 - 7
5 - 19
6 - 20
7 - 7
8 - 2
9 - 7
10 - 13
```

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал такой вариант для этого задания:

```
from random import randint


class Die():
    def __init__(self, sides = 6):
        """Инициализация кубика"""
        self.sides = sides
    
    def roll_die(self):
        """Функция рандомного числа"""
        return randint(1, self.sides)
    
    def roll_model(self):
        """Функция имитации броска"""
        print(f'\nSide Cube: {self.sides}\n')
        for i in range(10):
            print(f'Throw {i + 1}: {self.roll_die()}')
```

Тест:

```
cub_6 = Die()
cub_10 = Die(10)
cub_20 = Die(20)

cub_6.roll_model()
cub_10.roll_model()
cub_20.roll_model()
```

Результат:

```
Side Cube: 6

Throw 1: 5
Throw 2: 5
Throw 3: 2
Throw 4: 1
Throw 5: 2
Throw 6: 5
Throw 7: 6
Throw 8: 5
Throw 9: 2
Throw 10: 6

Side Cube: 10

Throw 1: 1
Throw 2: 5
Throw 3: 6
Throw 4: 4
Throw 5: 8
Throw 6: 6
Throw 7: 3
Throw 8: 8
Throw 9: 4
Throw 10: 2

Side Cube: 20

Throw 1: 13
Throw 2: 18
Throw 3: 17
Throw 4: 10
Throw 5: 5
Throw 6: 17
Throw 7: 9
Throw 8: 15
Throw 9: 5
Throw 10: 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Программирую почти 2 недели.
Вот так решил:

```
from random import randint

class Die():
    def __init__(self, sides = 6):
      self.sides = sides

    def roll_die(self):
      for i in range(10):
         x = randint(1, self.sides)
         print(x)


die = Die(20)   <--- тут менять числа на 10, 20

die.roll_die()
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]